# BigInt and (anynumber postfix n i.e. 200n) - Both methods should give the same answer in Javascript right? But, I am getting different answers

Tags: javascript

I thought that BigInt method and any number postfix `n` convention method are the same. Am I wrong? The issue explained below:

Firstly, I have summed two numbers i.e.

```
a = 812409329480932850928309582n;
b = 382759230958092895809328955n;
```

using any number postfix `n` convention method.

Secondly, I have summed the same numbers stored in a different variable i.e.

```
c = BigInt(812409329480932850928309582);
d = BigInt(382759230958092895809328955);
```

using `BigInt` method. But, the issue here is that I am getting different answers as shown in the picture. Can someone help me out here?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters passed by your code to the `BigInt()` constructor are plain numbers, and they're beyond the range of safely-representable integers. Thus those constants are imprecise as numbers, and your resulting `BigInt` values are incorrect.

Using the constant syntax is the way to do it if you have the actual constant values (strings of digits).

If you really want to use the constructor, you can pass the values in as strings instead of numeric constants. The constructor will correctly parse the strings as BigInt constants.

Comment: Perhaps add that if he passed the values to `BigInt` as strings, i.e. surrounded them with quotes, the answers would be equal.

Comment: @MikeM thanks, I was about to test that but I was distracted.